# How to index every element in an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, indexing, pyspark, slice

I have an ArrayType column where every element is also an array, of exactly 2 elements.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

data = [
  {"u": ["apple", 23]},
  {"u": ["banana", 12]}
]

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df.show()
```

```
+------------+
|           u|
+------------+
| [apple, 23]|
|[banana, 12]|
+------------+
```

I want to replace each inner array with its first element. Had I been writing vanilla Python, it would be:

```
result = [ar[0] for ar in array_of_arrays]
```

With Spark, I can use a UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f, types as t

fn = f.udf(lambda u: u[0], t.StringType())
new_df = df.select(fn(f.col("u")))

new_df.show()
```

```
+-----------+
|<lambda>(u)|
+-----------+
|      apple|
|     banana|
+-----------+
```

Which is the output I want. But how can I do this with PySpark, without:

- Using a UDF
- Exploding the array and re-aggregating after

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.element_at.html

Comment: @emma I can see how to use that to get the first array in my array of arrays, but not the first element of every array. Also, comments are generally for suggestions or clarification of the question rather than answering it.

Comment: It can apply to `ArrayType` column to get an element at index X for all arrays.  I suggested the starting point, however, without the some sample data, I cannot give you answer or more detail.

Comment: I see. Sounds like it would help if I add some more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.withColumn('u_1', col('u')[0]).show()

+------------+------+
|           u|   u_1|
+------------+------+
| [apple, 23]| apple|
|[banana, 12]|banana|
+------------+------+
```